# Transform any program into a semantically equivalent one

Tags: c, performance, optimization, compiler-construction

I recently found this theorem [here](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/tball/papers/XmasGift/), (at the bottom):

`Any program can be transformed into a semantically equivalent program of one procedure containing one switch statement inside a while loop.`

The Article went on to say :

`A corollary to this theorem is that any program can be rewritten into a program consisting of a single recursive function containing only conditional statements`

My questions are, are both these theorems applicable today ? Does similarly transforming a program reap any benefits ? I mean to say, is such a code optimized ? (Although recursion calls are slower, I know)

I read, from [here](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SwitchStatement), that switch-cases are *almost always* faster when optimized by the compiler. Does that make a difference. ?

PS: I'm trying to get some idea about compiler optimizations from [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler_optimization)

And I've added the `c` tag as that's the only language I've seen optimized.

Comment: The first article you cite is a little academic joke. Note that it says "a **folk** theorem" and not "a theorem". I would not try to learn anything about optimization from the first article.

Comment: @markgz From wikipedia : `folk theorem refers generally to any theorem that is believed and discussed, but has not been published`. You're right : it is bit of a troll. But the conclusions seem to be true nevertheless.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its true.  A Turing machine is essentially a switch statement on symbols that repeats forever, so its based pretty directly on Turing-machines-compute everything.   A switch statement is just a bunch of conditionals, so you can clearly write such a program as a loop with just conditionals.  Once you have that, making the loop from recursion is pretty easy although you may have to pass a lot of state variables as parameters if your language doesn't have true lexical scoping.

There's little reason to do any of this in practice.  Such programs generally operate more slowly than the originals, and may take more space.  So why would you possibly slow your program down, and/or make its load image bigger?

The only place this makes sense is if you intend to obfuscate the code.  This kind of technique is often used as "control flow obfuscation".

Comment: So, aside from obfuscation, such transforms serve no purpose at all. What if I use only `switch` and `while`, without using recursion at all ? Will there be a benefit ?

Comment: Generally, no.  The only point of doing a semantics-preserving transformation is to a) optimize some aspect of the transformed program with respect to the original, [and the type of transformations being discussed generally pessimize time or space, or b) to enable some *other* transformation to take place that provides such an optimization.   For an example of the latter, a complicated set of conditional reduced to a set of cases may all turn out to have the same case --> simpler switch --> possibly faster execution and definitely smaller code.  ...

Comment: ... but there are other ways to determine such optimizations (e.g., common subexpression elimination, partial redundancy elimination) which tend to be useful in many cases, and these optimizations tend to already be built into compilers.

Comment: Is such optimization done by the developer ? It would seem to be _very_ involved. Or are they done automagically by the compiler ?

Comment: Common subexpression/Partial redundancy are involved and hard in general.  They and many other optimizations are built into many compilers.  Go read a standard compiler text (Aho and Ullman, "Compilers" is a classic) to get a better understanding of the kind of transformations built into compilers.

Comment: @RaunakS What could be a "practical" application would be that you can transform any recursive computation into an iterative one. In some languages practical limitations (stacksize, no tail recursion, no recursion at all [early fortran]) may make that necessary and there exists a simple algorithm to do that in general. Other than that? Theoretical CS it is :)

Comment: @Voo: most practical optimizations require a series of transformations to achieve them.  Each transformation by itself has to be "semantics preserving" or the application won't produce the same result.   All that matters is the chain of transformations leads to a good result.   Very modern compilers may try alternative chains to achieve various good results.   Bleeding-edge software engineering research is pushing "search through transformation space" to find "good solutions" in terms of code structure.

Comment: @Ira Yeah after writing it I thought that that was a "bit" too general formulated. Clearly tail recursion is basically the application of the stated theorem in modern compilers, though I wouldn't put other transformations such as CSE or all different kinds of loop transformations there. The part about searching through transformation space instead of the usual stages of compiler optimization sounds interesting though - any paper for that? Don't really keep up with academical research (or even state of the art optimizations in gcc, hotspot), but once in a while that's fun.

Comment: @Voo Might it also be implementation environment dependent ? Such as for embedded systems : most of which are probably many years away from the bleeding edge. For instance, I remember Windows 3.1 being used as an embedded OS on aircraft till 2008. Any computation there would need to be _heavily_ optimized.

Comment: @Voo: Check out "future of search based software engineering" http://www.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/K.Lakhotia/readingGroup/FoSE-SBSE.pdf.  For a view of transformations for modifying code (not semantics preserving!), check out my paper on "Design maintenance systems" http://www.semdesigns.com/Company/Publications/DMS-CACM-1992-baxter.pdf

Comment: @RaunakS: Embedded systems may contain heavily optimized, because often they are produced in large quantity so cost per unit must be low, and that is achieved by using low performance parts pushed to the limit, and trading engineering optimization time to get some of the performance back.

Answer (score 3):

This is basically what happens when a compiler translates a program into machine code. The machine code runs on a processor, which executes instructions one-by-one in a loop. The complex structure of the program has become part of the data in memory.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive loops through a switch statement can be used to create a rudimentary virtual machine. If your virtual machine is Turing complete then, in theory, any program *could* be rewritten to work on this machine.

```
int opcode[] {
   PUSH,
   ADD
   ....
};

while (true) {
    switch (*opcode++) {
    case PUSH:
        *stack++ = <var>;
        break;
    case ADD:
        stack[-1] += stack[0];
        --stack;
        break;
     ....
    }
}
```

Of course writing a compiler for this virtual machine would be another matter. 
:-)

Comment: Would this be how modern virtual machines are written ? (for instance, the JVM)

Comment: The vm I have illustrated is similar to how a language like Python would be interpreted. That is the vm is designed to interpret, or emulate, the bytecode of a different machine. These would be more optimised though (e.g. a table of function pointers may be faster than a switch statement). VMs that virtualise windows or similar use different technologies altogether involving CPU extensions and low-level hackery.

Comment: Fascinating. I never realized how much machinery is hidden behind the compiler veil (and we never seem to learns such matters in college).

Comment: "We"?  Most computer science curricula have compiler classes, or at least they used to.  If you don't know how your programming language "works", you will likely not understand how to build big, reasonably efficient systems.

Comment: @IraBaxter We don't, unfortunately. We do have one semester of automata ... but no compiler design. Our syllabi seem to be more focused on IT.

Comment: Welcome to a lifetime of learning. Really good engineers do a lot of learning on their own beyond their school education.  Follow your nose and enjoy it.

Comment: @IraBaxter Good Advice, thank you. I've already begun the Aho- Compilers/Principle/Techniques text you had mentioned. That's a start.